# Global AJAX event listeners in Can.JS?

Tags: ajax, canjs

Is it possible to bind listeners to when an AJAX request is started in Can.JS? I want to integrate a little loading indicator in my Can.JS project so that users can see when data is being loaded from my server. Using the jQuery `$.ajaxStart` and `$.ajaxSend` events didn't work, however the `$.ajaxComplete` event did fire correctly.

Comment: The jQuery handlers should work. Could you maybe make a jsFiddle (fork it from http://jsfiddle.net/donejs/qYdwR/) that shows it not working?

Comment: My jsFiddle is on http://jsfiddle.net/WfMqn/1/ :)
As you can see, the Complete event fires while the Start event doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/WfMqn/1/) you are binding to the event on document.ready which is after you start the Ajax request. The complete log only shows because the document is ready and binds the event before the Ajax request returns. If you do everything in the correct order on `document.ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        console.log('start');
    }).ajaxComplete(function(){
        console.log("Complete");
    });

    var TestModel = can.Model({
        findAll: "GET http://jsfiddle.net/echo/json/"
    });

    TestModel.findAll({}, function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

It works as expected (see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfMqn/2/)).